# Proc sql: Copy one single row from one table to all rows in another table

Tags: sas, sql-update

I have two tables.

**Table A**:

```
a b
----
1 2 
3 4
```

and a table B with only one row

```
c d e
------
5 6 7
```

I want to create a new table which looks like this:

```
a b c d e
----------
1 2 5 6 7
3 4 5 6 7
```

i.e copy the single  row from B into all rows in A.
Note: Using SAS proc sql.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: Sorry. Have changed to SAS since I use sql inside SAS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add 3 columns to your `TableA`:

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD c INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD d INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD e INTEGER;
```

Then update `TableA` with the values from `TableB`:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.c = b.c, a.d = b.d, a.e = b.e
FROM TableA a CROSS JOIN TableB b;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7bcc1ee0444b08df6d82b389c65b97d2).
Results:

```
| a   | b   | c   | d   | e   |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 2   | 5   | 6   | 7   |
| 3   | 4   | 5   | 6   | 7   |
```

Comment: This actually works without adding new columns to A. I just did the cross join and select a.*,b.*. Is that a bad way doing it?

Comment: The title of your question is: *copy one single row from one table to all rows in another table* so I thought that you want to update the existing table. If all you need is a select statement then the CROSS JOIN is the way to go: `select a.*, b.* from tablea a cross join tableb b`

Comment: See the demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d9053125457919224e88db66c406694c

Answer (score 3):

Data step?

```
data want;
set A;
if _n_ = 1 then set B;
run;
```

Comment: I'm just including it for completeness. It answers the question correctly and things like `require sql` are preferences for the most part not actual requirements of the software or limitation of the software. If your company has chosen to use a SQL implementation that's a choice but it makes your life harder.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT IGNORE INTO Table A select * from Table B; so basically I am merging the two table, considering that the table DDL is the same.

Comment: Did not work in SAS proc sql. I have added this info to the question.